# Give the row number that contains a certain number in a specific column

Tags: excel

I have a table in excel with the following data:

```
      A       B      C
1    Name    Age    Fare
2    Owen    22     7.25
3    Lionel  36     0
4    John    38     71.3
5    Gladys  5      8
6    Mark    12     0
```

My problem is I want to locate the row numbers where the value for column C is zero (in my example, it will give the 3rd and 6th row). I'll appreciate any kind of help since the data I got has 1000 rows and locating the row number with a zero value for column C is a bit time-consuming. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use following formula in `D2` cell then drag and down as needed

```
=IF(C2=0,ROW(),"")
```

[image]

Comment: You are advised to accept (tick the answer as green) the the answer it solve your this problem so that other visitor can see it is useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
=MATCH(0,C:C,0)
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Place the above formula in **E1** and in **E2** enter:

```
=MATCH(0,INDEX(C:C,E1+1):INDEX(C:C,9999),0)+E1
```

and copy down ward until you see errors.

[image]

To avoid the appearance of errors use:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(0,INDEX(C:C,E1+1):INDEX(C:C,9999),0)+E1,"")
```

instead.

Comment: It worked! But I want to locate all the rows with a value of zero for column C. For example, if column C has a value of zero for the 3rd and 7th column, it will return 3 and 7.

Comment: @justin  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 0):

Select column D adjacent to column C used range and enter the formula in one cell, with all still highlighted,

`=IF(C2:C6=0,ROW())`

`C2:C6` being the used range in this case, and enter as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You can then filter the results and remove `FALSE` to leave the row numbers.

[image: Row number]